# three.js editor history: how do I get the commands into a script

Tags: three.js

So, as a web developer veteran (but a total, complete *3D noob*) I'm impressed by what I can do with my models in the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/)

I see I can "rewind" my actions in the editor by clicking on the commands listed in the *History* panel..

Is there an easy way to see the actual javascript that lies underneath these command buttons (similar to the way you can copy your recent commands from the *Log* panel in Clara.IO's editing platform)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up breakpoints around the DOM elements in the history pane. What I tried is open Developer Pane in Chrome, click `sources` pane, and set up an event listener event breakpoint for mouse click.

Now if you click an item in history pane, you will be brought to stop on the function `onClick` in `ui.three.js`. You can step in to examine the JS code it is about to execute.

Hope that helps.